# How to use Nginx to connect to my app in Docker image?

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy

My Nginx is not in docker image. My app is in docker image. They both live on the same server.

I don't want Nginx in a docker image, since it looks awful complex for me to configure. But my app is running in a docker container.

How to configure Nginx to use the docker image which my app is running in?

Here is my Nginx config file:

```
server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    my.domain.com;
       return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
       listen         443 ssl;
       server_name    www.nicolasxu.space nicolasxu.space;
       # add Strict-Transport-Security to prevent man in the middle attacks
       add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000"; 


       ssl_certificate /root/.ssh/nicolasxu.space.cert;
       ssl_certificate_key /root/nicolasxu.space.key;
       [....]
}
```

Comment: Is nginx a reverse proxy for a served application here? Or a classic web server?

Comment: @FrançoisMaturel Reverse proxy, not classic server. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To easily setup nginx (in docker host) as a reverse proxy in front of a dockerized webapp you could just `--publish` the port of your webapp and route the trafic to this port:

1. Run your docker container with [`--publish`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p-expose) argument to bind host port with container's webapp port, for instance with a jenkins container I would do:

   ```
   docker run --publish 127.0.0.1:8080:8080 --name jenkins jenkins
   ```

This binds port 8080 of the container to port 80 on localhost's `127.0.0.1` of the host machine (this avoids port 8080 to be opened to anyone if you don't use any firewall). The [Docker User Guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/) explains in detail how to manipulate ports in Docker.

2. Forward all incoming trafic as a [reverse proxy](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/) to the local container your port (8080 in my example)

   ```
   server {
       ...

       listen         443 ssl;
       server_name    www.nicolasxu.space nicolasxu.space;
       ...

       ssl_certificate ...

       location / {
               # forward all the trafic to docker container's published port
               proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
       }
   }
   ```

Setting SSL on nginx and routing the trafic as HTTP to dockerized webapp is a good practice and will work like a charm.

---

**Edit**

For maximum performances, you can also use :

```
docker run --network=host ...
```

When using `--network=host`, docker will instruct the container to use the hosts networking stack. You won't have to `--publish` ports on host as it is the same network stack, and web application will be available on it's native port.

Comment: It's lot of new knowledge. Thank you very much! Let me try that first!